# Creating a sum from a list within a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not too sure how to ask this, and I'm not all that experienced with programming, so you'll have to forgive me. Anyways, I have an issue. Basically, I need to come up with the sum of some numbers and also the average.

The program is supposed to have the user inputs values. They input a month and a number associated with that month, and then I need to get the average. So I have one big list, and then lists within that list. It basically looks like this:

```
    months = [["January", 3.45], ["February", 7.1865], ["March", 4.56]]
```

What I'm wondering is, how do I single out the second element in each list?
I was thinking that I could use a for loop and compiling the numbers into a separate list, but I tried that and I couldn't it to calculate correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions can help you here:

```
names = [item[0] for item in months]
numbers = [item[1] for item in months]
```

If you're using just plain `for` loops, things get much messier:

```
names = []
numbers = []

for item in months:
    names.append(item[0])
    numbers.append(item[1])
```

Answer (score 6):

Nobody's said this one yet:

```
sum(x[1] for x in monthlist)
```

As mentioned in the comments below, if you know each element in the `monthlist` is iterable and has exactly 2 elements, you can make this a little more explicit by unpacking the tuples as you go:

```
sum(value for month,value in monthlist)
```

---

This doesn't create an intermediate list just to pass to sum.  That's the beauty of generators.  The real beauty here is if monthlist were some sort of lazy iterator (e.g. a file object).  Then you could sum over it without storing more than one element in memory at a time:

```
#code to sum the first column from a file:
with open(file) as f:
    first_col_sum = sum(float(line.split()[0]) for line in f)
```

Comment: I like the named version too: `sum(num for name, num in monthlist)`, although it hardcodes the structure more than `x[1]`.

Comment: @DSM -- Added that version as well (thanks).  Usually in that case I'd use `sum(num for _,num in monthlist)`, but now I'm starting to  rethink that.  After all, why not give myself a reminder about what `monthlist` actually stores?

Answer (score 6):

Might as well make this an answer and not a comment.  The `zip` function works kind of like a zipper, combining matching elements:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
<zip object at 0xb6e5beec>
>>> list(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

and with the * operator, which basically turns f(*[a,b]) into f(a,b), we can go backwards:

```
>>> list(zip(*(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

So we can use `zip` to break apart your lists:

```
>>> list(zip(*months))
[('January', 'February', 'March'), (3.45, 7.1865, 4.56)]
>>> monthnames, numbers = zip(*months)
>>> monthnames
('January', 'February', 'March')
>>> numbers
(3.45, 7.1865, 4.56)
```

This is a little less efficient if you only care about one of them, but is a useful idiom to be familiar with.

Comment: Clever.  I wouldn't have thought of zip for this one.

Comment: Might want to make a comment that on py2k, `zip(*months)` returns a list whereas on py3k, it's an iterator "zip object".

Answer (score 3):

To extract the second element in each list:

```
numbers = [i[1] for i in months]
```

If you want to get the sum of all the numbers:

```
numbersum = sum(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option with [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

months = [["January", 3.45], ["February", 7.1865], ["March", 4.56]]
sum(map(itemgetter(1), months)) # what means sum all items where each item is retrieved from month using index 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding because I don't see it already.

```
>>> map(None,*months)
[('January', 'February', 'March'), (3.4500000000000002, 7.1864999999999997, 4.5599999999999996)]
```

So `map(None, *months)[1]` is the list you seek.

Comment: This is because `map(None, *x)` is the same as `zip(*x)`.

Comment: I don't think this will actually work in Python 3.  `list(map(None, *months))` gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`; I think they removed the None shortcut.